# Open the links one by one, and save the file to a destination sharepoint folder

Tags: excel, vba

Column B has links to files (.xls, .doc, .pdf, etc). I want a macro that will open the links one by one, and save a copy of the file to a destination sharepoint folder. Once it saves copy of one file, it should then pick the next link and do the same. Also, everytime the function is success, column b should get filled with green colour, else with red.

```
Sub OpenLinkAndSaveCopy()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim hyperlinkAddress As String
    
    ' Loop through each cell in column B
    For Each cell In Range("B1:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
        ' Check if the cell contains a hyperlink
        If cell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
            ' Get the hyperlink address
            hyperlinkAddress = cell.Hyperlinks(1).Address
            
            ' Open the hyperlink
            Workbooks.Open hyperlinkAddress
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```